# manage enum var in c (porting code from c++)

Tags: c++, c, enums

I´m trying to make a porting of a c++ code to an msp430 c code.
Since I never faced enumerated type, I´m getting few problem to undestand how to manage it.
This code was written from Taylor Andrews :
enum list are defined as:

```
    enum accel_odr
{
    A_POWER_DOWN,   // Power-down mode (0x0)
    A_ODR_3125,     // 3.125 Hz (0x1)
    A_ODR_625,      // 6.25 Hz (0x2)
    A_ODR_125,      // 12.5 Hz (0x3)
    A_ODR_25,       // 25 Hz (0x4)
    A_ODR_50,       // 50 Hz (0x5)
    A_ODR_100,      // 100 Hz (0x6)
    A_ODR_200,      // 200 Hz (0x7)
    A_ODR_400,      // 400 Hz (0x8)
    A_ODR_800,      // 800 Hz (9)
    A_ODR_1600      // 1600 Hz (0xA)
};
```

while mine is:

```
 typedef enum
{
    A_POWER_DOWN,   // Power-down mode (0x0)
    A_ODR_3125,     // 3.125 Hz (0x1)
    A_ODR_625,      // 6.25 Hz (0x2)
    A_ODR_125,      // 12.5 Hz (0x3)
    A_ODR_25,       // 25 Hz (0x4)
    A_ODR_50,       // 50 Hz (0x5)
    A_ODR_100,      // 100 Hz (0x6)
    A_ODR_200,      // 200 Hz (0x7)
    A_ODR_400,      // 400 Hz (0x8)
    A_ODR_800,      // 800 Hz (9)
    A_ODR_1600      // 1600 Hz (0xA)
}accel_odr;
```

than in the header file he define a var related to the enum as:

`uint16_t begin( accel_odr aODR = A_ODR_50);`
doing this operation, while compiling I get the error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

## 18 expected a ")"  LSM9DS0.c   /ACC    line 130    C/C++ Problem

and

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

## 256 type name is not allowed   main.c  /ACC    line 45 C/C++ Problem

What I´m missing?? I tryed to assign the value inside the function as:

```
uint16_t begin( accel_odr aODR);
```

aODR = A_ODR_50;

but I did´t solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with [tag:c#]. Removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint16_t begin( accel_odr aODR = A_ODR_50);
```

It is not a variable declaration, it's a function declaration with a [default argument value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument#Default_arguments_in_C.2B.2B). C++ has default arguments, but C has no default argument feature.

You can just declare it in C as:

```
    uint16_t begin(accel_odr aODR);
```

and if there is any call with no argument like `begin();`, replace them by `begin(A_ODR_50);`.